# Elixir error "erlang error: :guard_expr"

Tags: elixir

On the `iex` console, I found the following error that I'm unsure what I've done wrong...

```
case %{} do
  x when x == %{} -> true
  _x -> false
end
```

Results in the following error:

```
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :guard_expr
```

Also, I wanted to explain how I found this. I attempted to make my own `||` macro by looking at elixir's implementation and changing it to treat `[]`, `{}`, and `%{}` the same as `false` and `nil`.
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2313

Here's that implementation (it has the same problem):

```
defmodule Or do
  defmacro left || right do
    quote do
      case unquote(left) do
        x when x in [false, nil] or x == [] or x == {} or x == %{} ->
          unquote(right)
        x ->
          x
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Taking away the `or x == %{}` makes things work.

Comment: Strange. Using a variable in place of the literal compiles, i.e: `y = %{}; case y, do: (x when x == y -> true; _x -> false)`

Comment: Yes and its only maps that cause a problem, [] or something else doesn't crash it.

Comment: Strangely, when this same guard is used in a function definition it does not crash...

Comment: It appears this is an Erlang bug. I could reproduce this in the pure Erlang shell. I can't find any reference about this behaviour. In any case, until this gets resolved, you should consider some workaround, such as the one proposed by @Christian.

Comment: Agreed with @sasajuric, seems to be an Erlang bug.

Comment: Where should I report it? The erlang/otp github repo doesn't seem to accept issues.

Comment: Maybe on Erlang bugs mailing list (http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs). This is the Erlang code that reproduces it: `case #{} of X when X == #{} -> X end.` I should mention I tried with Erlang 17.0. Perhaps it's fixed on 17.4, but I don't have it installed to verify.

Comment: You may want to post an answer to your own question to indicate that this appears to be an Erlang bug.  Or maybe @Christian could post his workaround along with the details about a potential Erlang bug. Someone might find this question and, of course, the comments explain it but it might be wise to add an answer as well.  Just a suggestion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an Erlang bug. Here is the erlang code to reproduce the issue:

```
case #{} of X when X == #{} -> X end.
```

Thanks to everyone for confirming! See comments for more details.